# Задача на python. Игра в лесенку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Текст задачи:

Дети играют в «лесенку»: первый подтянулся a раз. Второй на 1 раз больше. Первый снова на 1 раз больше, и так далее. В последний раз игрок сумел подтянуться b раз. Сколько всего подтягиваний было в игре?

Нужно посчитать сумму чисел от a до b. Программа запрашивает два числа и выводит результат — одно число, а как это сделать, я немножко не разобрался

На картинке образец как должно выглядеть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отлично. Решайте задачу.

Comment: решается в одну строчку (без учета запроса данных, это еще две строчки). Любой девятиклассник, который не хлопал ушами на уроках математики, знает, как решить.

Answer (score 1):

Можно в одну строчку

```
sum(range(a, b+1))
```

Comment: Можно, но лучше по другому. Есть простая формула для нахождения суммы членов арифметической последовтельности.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
print((b-a+1)*(a+b)/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
print('Количество подтягиваний в игре составило ', str(sum(range(int(input('Введите первое целочисленное значение: ')), int(input('Введите второе целочисленное значение: ')) + 1))) + '.')
```

Ход выполнения программы:

print('Количество подтягиваний в игре составило ' + str(sum(range(int(**input('Введите первое целочисленное значение: ')**), int(**input('Введите второе целочисленное значение: '))** + 1))) + '.')

|
|
/

print('Количество подтягиваний в игре составило ' + str(sum(range(**int('5')**, **int('5')** + 1))) + '.')

|
|
/

print('Количество подтягиваний в игре составило ' + str(sum(**range(5, 5 + 1)**)) + '.')

|
|
/

print('Количество подтягиваний в игре составило ' + str(sum(**range(5, 6)**)) + '.')

|
|
/

print('Количество подтягиваний в игре составило ' + str(**sum([5, 5])**) + '.')

|
|
/

print('Количество подтягиваний в игре составило ' + **str(10)** + '.')

|
|
/

print(**'Количество подтягиваний в игре составило ' + '10' + '.'**)

|
|
/

**print('Количество подтягиваний в игре составило 10.')**

|
|
/

Вывод:

> Введите первое целочисленное значение: **5**
>     Введите первое целочисленное значение: **5**
>   Количество подтягиваний в игре составило 10.

Comment: Дико длинная строка, совершенно не требуется ``list()``, точка выводится на другой строке. А для вычисления суммы арифметической последовательности есть простая формула, что даст нам О(1).

Comment: И действительно. Я попытался расписать ход выполнения программы.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
C=0
for i in range(a,b+1):
    C=C+i
print(C)
```

Comment: Не короткий, но правильный

Comment: Если не трудно отметь галочкой